# salesforce unable to set user as inactive via apex in force.com site

Tags: user

I am using the code below in my force.com site. All I want is when this code executes the user should be set as inactive. But is giving an unknow error in my site.

```
u =[Select IsActive from User where id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];            
u.IsActive = false;

update u;
```

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Dude, do you really want to deactivate yourself?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot deactivate self using Apex code. This will throw **FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Cannot de-activate self** 
If you try deactivating some other User, this code will work conceptually. But there are several factors associated around successfully deactivating a User. 
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000193654&language=en_US
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=deactivating_users.htm&language=en_US